# flot graph not showing when xaxis

Tags: javascript, php, flot

when i try to output a graph i get a blank screen,

works when i remove the xaxis and yaxis options... not sure what to do.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Chart1
    var chart1Options = {
      series: {
        lines: { show: true },
        color: "#fff",
        points: { show: true }
      },
       valueLabels: { show: true },
        grid: {
          backgroundColor: { colors: ["#4ca8fa", "#2887da"] },
          bordercolor: "#fff",
          borderwidth: "60",
          hoverable: true //IMPORTANT! this is needed for tooltip to work
    },
    xaxis: { mode: "time",  timeformat: "%y/%m/%d", axisLabel: 'Date' },
    yaxis: { axisLabel: 'Result'}
    }; var dataset1 = { label: "result", data: <?php echo json_encode($dataset1); ?>,};

    $.plot($("#chart1"), [ dataset1 ], chart1Options);
</script>
```

any help appreciated.

Comment: Is there any output on the error console?

Comment: Are you loading `jquery.flot.time.js`?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Near this line you are missing closing php tag.                                          `**data: <?php echo json_encode($dataset1);**` //close missing                                           This may help you.